# Android - failed-to-initialize-monitor-thread-unable-to-establish-loopback-connection

Tags: android

Since I am a new user all links I have removed the http: on them so that I can post what I have done so far in troubleshooting.

I am taking a class in android development and have installed/downloaded the following

JDK 7
JDK 6
Eclipse IDE for Java
Android SDK

Java code runs without any problem in this Eclipse. For running Android:

at first, I went into Eclipse-> Help menu and then Install New Software.
Clicked Add, named it ADT and for location used: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse.

The new window that appears, I have clicked all of those boxes and choose Next. Upto this point, everything is OK, ADT is installed and I am be asked to restart Eclipse. When Eclipse launches, a new window appears and asks me to either install the Android Software Development Kit (SDK) or choose an existing SDKs location. I chose to install Android Software Development Kit (SDK) (I checked all the options). I have set SDK location to the default location. After everything finishes I see two errors in the Eclipse console when it tries to reach out and install the packages.

```
 Failed to initialize monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection
```

and

```
 Cannot find tools in the android-sdk folder
```

I have turned off all tunneling from IPV6 and IPV4

- Disable the IPV6
- Turned off Firewalls

Add the -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to the eclipse.ini file

Followed all directions here.

//blogs.msdn.com/b/richin/archive/2010/11/26/how-to-disable-teredo-tunneling-pseudo-interface-6to4-adapter.aspx

//www.java.net/node/703177

//stackoverflow.com/questions/9011539/failed-to-initialize-monitor-thread-unable-to-establish-loopback-connection

//stackoverflow.com/questions/7300211/eclipse-ide-failed-to-initialize-monitor-thread-error-after-installing-android

//stackoverflow.com/questions/9114741/serious-problems-in-configuring-android-sdk-with-eclipse

Still No luck, I have done clean installs of both JAVA, Android SDK, Eclipse

I also downloaded Java 6 instead of 7 and put the compiler to 1.6

I have tried running the SDK manager, but I get the errors of

```
   Fetching //dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml

   Failed to fetch URL ://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Invalid argument: connect

   Fetched Add-ons List successfully

   Fetching URL: //dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml

   Failed to fetch URL //dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml, reason: Socket Invalid argument: connect
```

I have done - 
Android SDK Manager->Tools->Options and now CHECK the box that says:
force https://... sources to be fetched using http://

and then click Packages->Reload. - Still Get the same errors from above

I have run everything as administrator

I have put everything in the root of the c directory

I am running out of options on why I am unable to complete the installation once I get to the point of install the sdk inside eclipse.

Even though I am running 64 bit, I did everything through 32, the only thing left is to download everything in 64 bit to see if that makes any difference.

Anyone with answer or suggestions please let me know thanks.

I got it to run only on my wife laptop, but on my desktop nothing so far.  I run Win 7 Pro X64 and my Ethernet is a Bigfoot Network killer Ethernet card.

Comment: Did everything with 64 bit, same thing nothing is working very very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

i had to update an additional line in eclipse.ini as well:

i updated java to 1.7, and had to tell eclipse about it.

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7